# How to install pandas library in Atom IDE/Platformio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, platformio

I have to use pandas/ipython for a data analysis app I am working on, and when I type in "pip install pandas/ipython", it returns a syntax error.

I have already tried "from pandas install pandas"

pip install pandas
pip install ipython

I expected no output, but instead I got

File "2app.py", line 1
    pip install pandas
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Is there anything I could do about this?

Comment: `from pandas install pandas` is not a valid statement, and `from pandas import pandas` will cause an `ImportError`

Comment: With what have you download Python? Pandas is usually download with it (like many other libraries) . 
To import pandas in a project do : `import pandas`  People usually do `import pandas as pd` so that you have to write less when you want to use a pandas function

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to run pip from the Python REPL. You should exit the REPL and run pip from a system command shell. What operating system are you running on?